# Fixed Width Stacked Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

How would I add a fixed width (not matter what the data value is) for the ApexChart horizontal stacked bar chart? This is what I am using: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked/ .

Any help is greatly appreciated :)!

Answer (score 0):

Use `width` property :

```
 chart: {
        type: "bar",
        height: 350,
        width:150,
        stacked: true
      },
```